# How to avoid the smooth effect in SpriteKit?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, skspritenode

I'm working with very small sprites, in order to create a retro game with pixellated sprites. But when I change the scale of my sprites to make them bigger, Sprite Kit smoothes the sprites and thats not what I want.

Is there any way to keep a sprite pixellated when I increase its scale ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could play with texture filtering mode .Nearest (default is .Linear). 
Texture filtering modes can be used  when the texture is drawn in a size other than its native size.

**SKTextureFilteringNearest**

> Each pixel is drawn using the nearest point in the texture. This mode
>   is faster, but the results are often pixelated.

Try and see where it will get you.

But you should keep in mind that some artefacts will always occur when scaling a bitmap (especially if you use filtering mode .Nearest)

Comment: Thanks, for now its looks like exactly as I wanted, if some artefacts appears I'll just provide bigger images like @appzYourLife said.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of increasing the size of your sprites via code, you should provide bigger images. This way the definition of the textures will be preserved.

If you still need to change the size of a sprite during the gameplay you can always reduce them.